# Django-Rest-Framework: router not working

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have this base urls file:

```
url(r'^locations/', include('locations.urls')),
```

in `locations.urls.py` app i have following url references:

```
url(r'^/?$', LocationList.as_view()),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[a-zA-Z0-9\-\$]+)/?$', LocationDetail.as_view()),
url(r'services/?$', LocationServiceseList.as_view()),
url(r'services/(?P<service_id>[a-zA-Z0-9\-\$]+)/?$', LocationServicesDetail.as_view()),
```

For above url referce i want to user [routers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/.) of Django-Rest-framework

for `locations/services/` i created GenericViewSet from DRF and i tried router successfully made following changes in locations.urls:

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'services', LocationServiceSet)

url(r'^/?$', LocationList.as_view()),
url(r'^(?P<vehicle_id>[a-zA-Z0-9\-\$]+)/?$', LocationDetail.as_view()),
url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
```

Now i want to create router for `/locations/` endpoinsts and made following changes

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'services', LocationServiceSet)
router.register(r'', LocationSet)


url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
```

Getting 404 for `/locations/` with stacktrace shows although `/locations/services/` work fine:

```
^locations/ ^ ^services/$ [name='locationsservice-list']
^locations/ ^ ^services/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='locationsservice-detail']
^locations/ ^ ^/$ [name='locations-list']
^locations/ ^ ^/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='locations-detail']
```

Answer (score 2):

This is **happening because of an empty string `prefix` argument** to `router.register()` function for `LocationSet`.

When you used an empty string `''`  as `prefix` for registering the router, it generated the following urls. (Notice the **double slash in urls**)

```
locations//$ # double slash in urls
locations//(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ # double slash in urls
```

**To solve this,** you need to define and register this  router in base urls file instead of `locations/urls.py` with prefix value as `locations`.

```
# base urls.py
router = routers.SimpleRouter() 
router.register(r'locations', LocationSet)

...
url(r'^locations/', include('locations.urls')), # include app urls
url(r'^', include(router.urls)), # include router urls
```

Another solution is to use a non-empty string as `prefix` while registering the router for `LocationSet` in `locations/urls.py`.